# Azure Notification Hub | HubClient.SendTemplateNotificationAsync() --> result: null

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

#### Details

We're utilizing [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) for implementing push notifications in our app for ios and android. We're using [installations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.installation?view=azure-dotnet) in hopes to utilize [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-templates-cross-platform-push-messages). We've successfully posted installations to our notification hub.

Here's an actual installation within our hub

```js
{
    "installationId": "fh0496fb-ac92-f48a-6b0a-a67efaa8f907",
    "pushChannel": "<hidden for stackoverflow post, is actually valid push handle>",
    "pushChannelExpired": false,
    "platform": "apns",
    "expirationTime": "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z",
    "tags": [
        "Location:Boise",
        "UserEmail:<hidden for stackoverflow post, is actually valid email>"
    ],
    "templates": {
        "ApnsFull": {
            "body": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"title\":\".(title, 33)\", \"subTitle\":\"$(subTitle)\", \"body\":\"$(message)\"}}}",
            "tags": [
                "ApnsFull"
            ]
        },
        "ApnsSimple": {
            "body": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(message)\"}}",
            "tags": [
                "ApnsSimple"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

#### The issue

We're utilizing the ClientHub method [SendTemplateNotificationAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.sendtemplatenotificationasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_NotificationHubs_NotificationHubClient_SendTemplateNotificationAsync_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__). We're constructing [TemplateNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.templatenotification?view=azure-dotnet)s and appropriately setting the newly required [headers for iOS13](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/push-notification-updates-ios-13).
We receive a [NotificationOutcome](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationoutcome?view=azure-dotnet) as expected but what's confusing is that the outcome is always

```js
{
    "Success": 0,
    "Failure": 0,
    "Results": null
}
```

### The Question

Why aren't the notifications sending?

Thanks, let me know what other information you need about our setup in order to help provide a solution!

Answer (score 0):

This lack of any `Success` or `Failure` counts indicates there was some mismatch between the audience being sent to and what was actually registered in the database. This most often happens when using a tag query that doesn't match with the tags actually stored for the device intended.

When using `SendTemplateNotificationAsync`, are you providing a tag query parameter?

If you aren't using the tag query parameter, it *should* broadcast to all devices registered. In that case could you open up a support case in the Azure Portal so we can look more closely at your issue here and see what we can find?

Comment: Thanks Kyle a support case was opened in Azure Portal a couple days ago. I'll post updates.

Answer (score 0):

Azure support was very responsive but unfortunately we couldn't resolve this problem in time. Our team switched to Firebase Cloud Messaging and experienced a very smooth process integrating push notifications.